# XCode 8 project navigator gets extra gap on top

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode8

I notice that sometimes `XCode 8` have extra gaps (screenshot added) on top of the project navigator.

**Do you know the reason and how to fix it?**

I found **reloading (close and reload) the project fix it**, but what is the reason? or is it an `XCode 8` UI `bug`?

[image]